# commonsChunkPlugin not grouping node_modules

Tags: webpack, commonschunkplugin

I would like to move all common chunks of my bundles to a `vendor.[chunkhash].js` file. However after inspecting the output I see some `node_modules` are included more then once having a large impact on output size.

**Webpack commonsChunkPlugin**

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: "vendor",
    filename: "vendor.[chunkhash].js",
    minChunks(module, count) {
        const context = module.context;
        return context && context.indexOf("node_modules") >= 0;
    }
}),
```

**Output**
[image]

Am I doing this wrong? Be aware that the ´wizer-components´ are components which also need to be built but have been put in a separate folder because I use them throughout other projects. Running the dev server is working fine and all components are working.

Comment: have you managed to make it work?

Comment: @alex.mironov see answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the following param to the webpack config. This basically tells webpack to first look in my `js` folder, then the global `node_modules` and then the local `node_modules`.

Because of this webpack will always find `react` in the global `node_modules` allowing it to be bundled only once.

```
resolve: {
    modules: ["js", path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"), "node_modules"]
},
```

Comment: not sure if I fully got it. could you please take  a look at this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361519/duplications-when-using-commonschunkplugin
I use modules: ["app", "api-layer", path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"), "node_modules"], but it doesn't seem to fix the issue entirely